# What does it mean that footprint/core OS is 400 bytes?

Tags: operating-system, tinyos, memory-footprint, footprint

I am researching TinyOS for a school assignment and read that the "core OS is 400 bytes", and another source saying "The footprint of TinyOS is 400 bytes" What exactly does this mean? Is it the actual space it occupies on harddrive?
How big ia a "traditional" OS such as windows?

The answers I have found of what "footprint" actually means is confusing too. Because it seems to mean both actual physical space and memory/disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to explain a bit of background, the [authors of TinyOS themselves have explained that](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~culler/cs294-f03/papers/tinyos.pdf) TinyOS isn't really an operating system:

> TinyOS has a component-based programming model, codified  by  the 
>   nesC  language, a dialect of C. TinyOS is not an OS in the traditional
>   sense; it is a programming framework for embedded systems and set of
>   components that enable  building an  application-specific OS  into
>   each application. A typical application is about 15K in size, of which
>   the base OS is about 400 bytes; the largest application, a
>   database-like query system, is about 64K bytes.

TinyOS is a software build system designed to allow software engineers to more easily build software for really tiny devices ([like this wireless sensor](http://www.memsic.com/userfiles/files/Datasheets/WSN/telosb_datasheet.pdf)), which do not have a harddrive. Instead, the program is typically stored inside the microcontroller of the device - the device I linked to for example has 48k bytes of flash memory (small embedded devices like these often use flash memory to store their program). 48k of code isn't very much, so it's really important that when you're making software to load onto the device, it takes up as little space as possible.

So, the 'base footprint of 400 bytes' means that, on top of the code that you (the software engineer) write to do whatever your tiny device needs to do, the TinyOS framework (which supports and provides services for your code) only adds an extra 400 bytes (which is really amazing!) to your program code which will actually be loaded onto the device's flash memory. However, this isn't the only overhead - depending on the device, TinyOS may also include various different supporting drivers for whatever chips and components exist on that device.

See [figure 6 in this paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~culler/papers/ai-tinyos.pdf) for some examples of actual program sizes.

Because of this I have found that building the same application for different devices using TinyOS can yield very different results. For example if I build a really simple program for the MicaZ wireless sensor I get:

```
compiled NullAppC to build/micaz/main.exe
         610 bytes in ROM
           4 bytes in RAM
```

Which means that the total program code, plus the base OS (400 bytes) is 610 bytes (the program will also use 4 bytes of RAM). However if I build the same program for TelosB:

```
compiled NullAppC to build/telosb/main.exe
        1328 bytes in ROM
           6 bytes in RAM
```

1328 bytes! Clearly TelosB requires a lot more additional software, presumably because the components on the TelosB require more complicated additional driver software.